# spring-boot-security 2.2.5 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/Argon2Parameters

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot security version 2.2.5.RELEASE in that , I am creating a custom password encoder with Argon2PasswordEncoder as my password encoder.

In this when i run, can see following error in the Argon2PasswordEncoder.java where i can see these two imports are missing,

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.Argon2BytesGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.Argon2Parameters;
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/params/Argon2Parameters$Builder
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.argon2.Argon2PasswordEncoder.encode(Argon2PasswordEncoder.java:78) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.custom.CustomPasswordEncoder.encode(CustomPasswordEncoder.java:11)
```

Please suggest me want to do, am I missing some dependency or its the spring boot version issue. And also how to overcome.
Many thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/7045 and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5354

Comment: Yes , i saw these pages before posting the question. I wanted to how to solve the issue with the version what i am using? And why did you give negative rating?

Answer (score 6):

I got the issue. for the version 2.2.5 springboot we need to explicitly add the dependency for Argon2BytesGenerator, Argon2Parameters nt found issue, since its not included in this version.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.64</version>
</dependency>
```